# Factor of 4 discrepancy between integral of Planck's law vs Stefan-Boltzmann law

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

Consider an absolutely black sphere with unit surface area and temperature $T$. [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law) states for the power emitted per unit area of the emitter per unit solid angle of emission per unit wavelength:

$$B_\lambda(\lambda,T)=\frac{2hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac1{\exp\left(\frac{hc}{\lambda k_B T}\right)-1}.\tag1$$

Multiplying it by the complete solid angle $4\pi$ and unit surface area, and then integrating it over all wavelengths should give the total power emitted:

$$P(T)=4\pi\int_0^\infty B_\lambda(\lambda,T)\,d\lambda=\frac{8k_B^2\pi^5}{15c^2h^3}T^4.\tag2$$

But, according to [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law), I should have obtained 4 times smaller result:

$$P(T)=\frac{2\pi^5k_B^4}{15c^2h^3}T^4.\tag3$$

Wikipedia says that the expression for Stefan-Boltzmann law gives

> total energy radiated per unit surface area of a black body across all wavelengths per unit time

and for Planck's formula it's

> power emitted per unit area of the body, per unit solid angle of emission, per unit frequency *[wavelength, in my case]*.

Energy per unit time is power, solid angle is taken into account by the factor $4\pi$ in $(2)$, wavelengths are eliminated by integration. So it would seem that $(2)$ should be equal $(3)$. But it isn't.

So, what's the reason for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stefan-Boltzmann law is
$$
 \frac{P}{A}=\frac{2\pi^5 k^4}{15 h^3 c^2} T^4,
\tag{1}
$$
where $P/A$ denotes the emitted power per unit surface area of the blackbody. In equation (1), the coefficient of $T^4$ is the **Stefan-Boltzmann constant**. In contrast, the energy per unit volume ($E/V$) of the radiation *inside* the blackbody is
$$
 \frac{E}{V}=\frac{8\pi^5 k^4}{15 h^3 c^3} T^4.
\tag{2}
$$
In equation (2), the coefficient of $T^4$ is the [**radiation constant**](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/RadiationConstant.html). Equation (2) is used, for example, to compute the energy density of the cosmic microwave background radiation, because in that case we are *inside* the blackbody (the universe). These two quantities are related to each other by
$$
 \frac{P}{A} = \frac{c}{4}\times \frac{E}{V}.
$$
The question is, where does the factor of $4$ come from?

The essence of the answer is that *inside* the blackbody, the radiation at any point is coming and going equally in *all directions*; but *outside* the blackbody, that is no longer true. The distribution over directions is not uniform outside the body, and the difference ends up being a factor of $4$. Equation (1) describes the emitted power *outside* the blackbody, whereas equation (2) describes the energy density *inside*.

The derivation of *both* equations, (1) and (2), involves the quantity $B(\lambda)$ that was given in the OP. Consider the quantity
$$
\frac{4\pi}{c}B(\lambda)\,d\lambda
\tag{3}
$$
where $d\lambda$ is an infinitesimal range of wavelengths. The quantity (3) is the energy density of the electromagnetic (EM) radiation that is contained *inside* the blackbody, within the given range of wavelengths. The factor of $4\pi$ accounts for the full sphere's worth of possible directions of the radiation *at each point* inside the blackbody. Integrating (3) over all wavelengths gives the total energy density (2).

To derive the Stefan-Boltzmann law (1), suppose for a moment that radiation is only able to escape through a small hole of area $A$ in the surface of the blackbody. How much energy leaks out per unit time? If we consider plane waves moving in a particular direction, then the amount that escapes through the hole *depends on the direction* in which the plane wave is moving compared to the orientation of the hole. So, to calculate this, we should start with the quantity
$$
\frac{1}{c}B(\lambda)\,d\lambda,
\tag{4}
$$
which is the energy density *per unit solid angle* inside the blackbody. This is obtained from (3) by omitting the factor of $4\pi$. EM radiation travels at speed $c$, so the energy per unit time that escapes through the hole into a given narrow cone of solid angle $d\Omega$ is
$$
\frac{1}{c}B(\lambda)\,d\lambda\times cA\cos\theta\,d\Omega
\tag{4}
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle of the radiation's direction of travel relative to the direction normal to the hole. The factor $A\cos\theta$ is the area of the hole projected orthogonally to the direction in which the radiation is traveling. **This is the key.** To calculate the rate at which energy escapes, we should integrate the quantity (4) over all directions with $\theta < \pi/2$. Directions with $\theta > \pi/2$ don't contribute, because that radiation is moving toward the inside of the body instead of toward the outside. Doing this integral (and cancelling the factors of $c$) gives
$$
B(\lambda)\,d\lambda\times A
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta\,\sin\theta\,\cos\theta
= B(\lambda)\,d\lambda\times A\pi,
\tag{5}
$$
so the quantity
$$
\pi B(\lambda)\,d\lambda
\tag{6}
$$
is the power per unit surface area of the radiation that escapes from the hole. Even though this analysis considered radiation escaping through a "hole" in the surface, the same analysis applies to every piece of the surface of a blackbody that allows radiation to escape. The Stefan-Boltzmann law comes from integrating (6) over all wavelengths.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account the Lambert cosine law, which add a $\cos (\theta )$ factor. Is is explained at the end of the wikipedia article.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law