# Does the formula for total energy emitted by black body considers only 1 solid angle, or the whole sphere?

Tags: thermal-radiation

According to Stephen-Boltzmann law [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law),

> the total energy radiated per unit surface area of a black body across
> all wavelengths per unit time

is:

$$j=\sigma T^4$$

So the total energy radiated accounting for the whole surface area is $E_{total}=\sigma T^4 A$.

I also know that the quantity:

$$\frac{2h\nu^3}{c^2}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{h\nu}{kT}}-1}$$

quoting from Wikipedia, is:

> is the amount of power per unit surface area per unit solid angle per
> unit frequency emitted at a frequency $\nu$, by
> a black body at temperature $T$.

I integrate this function between $\nu=0$ and $\nu=\infty$. I get $\frac{1}{\pi}\sigma T^4$. So the total energy emitted by a black budy in all directions must be $\sigma T^4$ times its surface area $A$, times solid angle $4\pi$ (since we want radiation emitted in all directions), ie

$$E_{total} = 4 \sigma T^4A$$

As we can see, the results don't agree. **Which formula then gives the total energy radiated from the whole of the black body in all directions in unit time?** Why is the reasoning which gave the wrong result wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Black Body is a Lambertian radiator, that means you need to weight the integral over solid angle with $\cos{\theta}$:

$$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi} 2} B(\nu, T) \cos{\theta}d\Omega$$

Note, also, that the polar angle stops at $\pi/2$ because you don't count radiation going back into the Black Body.

I believe each one of those is a factor of $\frac 1 2$, accounting for your $4\times$ result.

Comment: Thanks! I have some problems with the $\theta$ bit though: why the limit is not from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$? I am looking at this figure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert's_cosine_law#/media/File:Lambert_Cosine_Law_1.svg - based on this I don't get the 0 limit.

Comment: I was wrong, your limits are correct. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/462202/212053